# EaselJS : Help understanding animationend event

Tags: events, sprite, easeljs, createjs

In trying to figure out how to start and stop Sprite animations from a SpriteSheet, I tried this:

```
        // other code...

        // define animations in SpriteSheet:
        "animations": {"intro": [0, 19, "false"]}

        // other code...

        var spriteSheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet(data);
        var intro = new createjs.Sprite(spriteSheet, "intro");
        stage.addChild(intro);
        createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);

        intro.stop();

        var btnStart = document.getElementById("btnStart");

        btnStart.onclick = function() {
            console.log("btnStart clicked");
            intro.on("animationend", onStartAnimEnd);
            intro.play();
        };

        function onStartAnimEnd(e) {
            intro.removeEventListener("animationend", onStartAnimEnd);
            console.log("Start anim ended");
        }
```

In the above example, if the user clicks the btnStart button, the onStartAnimEnd callback fires indefinitely, even though by defining "false" in the animation configuration to signal we want to stop on the last frame, and the animation does in fact stop, *and* I'm removing the event listener in the first line of the callback.

If I add:

```
        function onStartAnimEnd(e) {
            intro.removeEventListener("animationend", onStartAnimEnd);
            intro.stop();
            console.log("Start anim ended");
        }
```

The problem goes away, but that doesn't seem right... So, if I change the listener assignment of the animationend event from:

```
            intro.on("animationend", onStartAnimEnd);
```

to:

```
            ask.addEventListener("animationend", onAskAnimEnd);
```

...and with this change, the indefinite event captures goes away.  So my questions are:

- What's the difference with these two event listener assignments?
- Is this animationend event continually firing in the background because we're updating the stage on the tick event, even though nothing needs re-rendering?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a duplicated question. As I answered you previous question, your animation definition is wrong, you need to use the boolean value (`false`) and not the string value (`"false"`).

Now sure what `ask` is, but the method `on` is a wrapper for `addEventListener`, and where you can specify things such as the scope of the callback and if it will run only once. Take a look at the API to know more:

http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/EventDispatcher.html#method_on